# Why the method IsInRole not working custom RoleProvider asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have implemented custom membership .Here is my custom MembershipProvidet and my Custom RoleProvide

```
public class FinkaynMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{

    BLL.GestionUserAccount gestionUserAccount = new BLL.GestionUserAccount();
    #region Unimplemented MembershipProvider Methods
    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get
        {
           return  "FinKayn";
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override bool EnablePasswordReset
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }




   public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
    {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public static long FinKaynUserId
   {
       //long FinKaynUserId = 0;
       get
       {
           if (HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"] != null && Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"]) != 0)
               return Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"]);
           else
           {
               HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["FinKaynUserId"];
               if (myCookie != null)
               {
                   HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"] = Convert.ToInt64(myCookie.Value);
                   // Session["User"] = (new UserManager()).GetUser(Convert.ToInt64(Session["UserId"]));
                   return  Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"]);
               }
               else
                  return 0;
           }
       }
       set
       {
           HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("FinKaynUserId");
           cookie.Value = value.ToString();
           cookie.Secure = false;
           cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
           HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
           HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"] = value;
       }

   }

   public  MembershipUser GetUser(string userId)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
   {
         //MembershipUser   userRep = new MembershipUser();
          entities.UserAccount user = gestionUserAccount.getUserAccount(username);
          if (user != null)
          {
              MembershipUser memUser = new MembershipUser("FinkaynMembershipProvider", username, user.IdUser, user.Email,
                                                          string.Empty, string.Empty,
                                                          true, false, DateTime.MinValue,
                                                          DateTime.MinValue,
                                                          DateTime.MinValue,
                                                          DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
              return memUser;
          }
          return null;
    }
    public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        get { return 6; }
    }
    public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
    public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
    public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion





    public override bool ValidateUser(string email, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Trim()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Trim())) return false;
       // password=(new CryptoEngine()).Encrypt(password);
        entities.UserAccount user = gestionUserAccount.authentifier(email, password);



        if (user == null)
        {
           // User = new UserAccount();
            return false;
        }
        if (user.IdUser>0)
        {
           // User = user;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }




}

public class FinKaynRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{

     GestionRole gestionRole = new GestionRole();
     GestionUserAccount gestionUserAccount = new GestionUserAccount();

    public FinKaynRoleProvider()
    {

    }

   public override string ApplicationName
   {
       get
       {
           return "finkayn";
       }
       set
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }

   public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
   {
       base.Initialize(name, config);

       //IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainerFactory().Create();
      // accountRepository = container.Resolve<IAccountRepository>();
   }
   public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
   {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
   public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// roles of a user ,acutually it's userName =email in our case
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="email"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
   public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string email)
   {

       return gestionUserAccount.GetRolesForUser(email);

  }

   public override bool IsUserInRole(string email, string roleName)
   {
       string[] userRoles = this.GetRolesForUser(email);

       return userRoles.Contains(roleName);
   }
   public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
   {
       return (new GestionRole()).RoleExists(roleName);
   }
   public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   public override string[] GetAllRoles()
   {
       return (new GestionRole ()).GetAllRoles();
   }
```

}

In the view of Master page : i have a link that has to been seen jut by a role (roles are stored in a table  Role ,a user can have many roles)

```
         <a>
         <%if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")){%>
            <%=Html.ActionLink("Places", "Places", "Places")%>
        <%} %>
        </a>
```

According to this question:[custom RoleProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973894/mvc-custom-roleprovider-how-to-hook-it-up-to-httpcontext-current-user-isinrole)

GetRolesForUser should be executed when IsInRole called.I've put a breakpoint on it ,but nothing happens.What's the problem?

I have added the roleprovider in web.config too:

```
      <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="../Auth/signin" timeout="2880" path="/" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="FinkaynMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="FinkaynMembershipProvider" type="FinkaynMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="FinKaynConnectionString"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>

</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="FinKaynRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true"   >
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="FinKaynRoleProvider" type="FinKaynRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Does anything else get called?  Do you have the provider configured in your web.config?

Comment: yes its cofigured in the web.config

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your membership provider; it may be overriding the default role check code.  You should post that as well.

Comment: @Jacob it's posted.check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried fully qualifying your role provider in your web.config.  The type attribute should have the types namespace included.

Also change your GetRolesForUser method's parameter name back to username

Comment: i have put it in app_data with no namespace.

Comment: @user594166, `App_Data`? Did you mean `App_Code`? And if you meant `App_Code` why are you using it in an ASP.NET MVC application. And if you meant `App_Data`, know that this folder shouldn't be used to put your source code files.

Comment: Who said that.I have seen the membership works i have used it in a view with and it workds :<a id="SignoutHref" runat="server">
              <%if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){%>
                     <%= Html.ActionLink("sign out", "Signout", "Home")%>

                      
                
                <%} %>
               <%else{%>
                  <%= Html.ActionLink("Sign in", "signin", "Auth")%>
                 
                <%}%>

             

              </a>

Comment: I'd recommend  you move your role provider to the root of your site and follow the above steps. As Darin states, App_Data is not the place for your source code

Comment: @NinjaNye i ll do it. and check, even you haven't justified.

Comment: It's not working now i have added a folder calle Membership ==>namespace finkayn.Membership and changed the types in web.config but it's not working again.

Comment: Updated:working now.Thanks NinjaNye.I moved the class outside app_data