# RoleProvider Enum HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So, I created with the help of others a custom role provider and attribute using enums. This is working perfectly, well almost perfectly, but working!
EX: [CustomRoles(MyRoles.Admin|MyRoles.User)]

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

or better yet

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(MyRoles.Admin)
```

Always return false.

How do I get this working? Code examples would help greatly.

Also, I know that there might be a better way, instead of enums in roles, but this is the way I want it. I have no problems converting enums to strings and back.

I've spent the last 4 hours researching this very issue online and found a couple of good proposals but its not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, this is Forms authentication and tried this post but couldn't figure out how to use the IsInRole method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973894/mvc-custom-roleprovider-how-to-hook-it-up-to-httpcontext-current-user-isinrole